# Orchard CMS: Is it possible to get previous ContentItem version to edit?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

Currently I can preview any version of ContentItem version by url like this: 
/Contents/Item/Display/14?version=2

Can I edit ContentItem same way? 
In fact I want to see previous values of non-rendered fields and parts, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable AuditTrail module, probably you can have access through: /Orchard.AuditTrail/Content/Detail/21312?version=2